# The file format and extension dont match when using closexml?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, export

I have a working method, that export to excel, but the issue is file extension is not support and being not format. This is not user friendly, how can I improve this from not allow a user to see this issue?

```cs
// controller
public void ExportToExcel()
{
    var v = new GridView();
    v.DataSource = this.GetExtractionViewModels();
    v.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExtractionRecords.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
    v.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    //return View("DataResult");
}
```

Comment: What you're doing here is exporting HTML content into an "ExtractionRecords.xls" file. This trick works because MS Excel (and other applications) are able to figure out that the file is of HTML format so it will read it as such. But you cannot avoid that dialog. If you don't want to have that warning then you need to create a real Excel file (not an HTML file that is renamed to ".xls").

Comment: @Mario how can i amend it on my method? Yes i need something on that to avoid that dialog

Comment: There is no built-in solution in .NET for creating Excel files. So, you will need to decide what library to use. Try searching for "Excel" on NuGet, you'll find a lot of libraries there. Which one you'll choose will depend on your exact needs (do you want to save old ".xls" or new ".xlsx" files or both, do you need a simple API or can you manage with more complex/tedious code, do you want fast execution or low memory consumption or both, etc...).

Comment: @Mario i want fast execution, I already have closeXML library

Comment: Then check the library's documentation, it definitely has examples for creating a workbook, adding a worksheet, and adding cells to the worksheet.

Comment: @Mario i am busy looking at the documentation for using workbook in c#